# How can I destroy all the shaders in the world?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script check if specific GameObjects exist then destroy them and add new same GameObjects.
If not exist it will add a new once anyway. The idea is to destroy anyway if exist and then add new o make it clean and not messed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ObjectsReplace : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabToInit;
    public bool deleteAllShaders = false;

    private const string c_doorRight = "Door_Right";
    private const string c_doorLeft = "Door_Left";
    private const string c_doorShieldFxLocked = "DoorShieldFXLocked";

    public List<GameObject> FindDoors(string[] SpecificParents, bool AllParents)
    {
        GameObject[] doorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorLeft);
        GameObject[] doorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorRight);

        List<GameObject> allDoors = doorsLeft.Union(doorsRight).ToList();

        if (AllParents == false)
        {
            List<GameObject> toRemove = new List<GameObject>();
            for (int i = 0; i < allDoors.Count; i++)
            {
                bool match = true;
                for (int x = 0; x < SpecificParents.Length; x++)
                {
                    match &= allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != SpecificParents[x];
                }
                if (match)
                {
                    toRemove.Add(allDoors[i]);
                }
            }
            foreach (var it in toRemove)
            {
                allDoors.Remove(it);
            }
        }

        return allDoors;
    }

    public void DeleteAllShaders()
    {
        if(deleteAllShaders == true)
        {
            FindDoors(null, true);


        }
    }

    public void UpdateOrAddShaderPrefabToDoors()
    {
        var allDoors = FindDoors(new string[]{ "Wall_Door_Long_01", "Wall_Door_Long_02" }, false);

        HashSet<GameObject> prefabParentsOfDoorsNeedRemove = new HashSet<GameObject>();
        allDoors.ForEach(doorGameObject =>
        {
            List<GameObject> shadersChildren = new List<GameObject>();
            for (int i=0; i<doorGameObject.transform.childCount ;i++)
            {
                if (doorGameObject.transform.GetChild(i).name.StartsWith(c_doorShieldFxLocked))
                {
                    shadersChildren.Add(doorGameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
                }
            }
            foreach (GameObject shader in shadersChildren)
            {
                GameObject outermostPrefabInstanceRoot = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(shader);
                prefabParentsOfDoorsNeedRemove.Add(outermostPrefabInstanceRoot);
            }
        });

        foreach (GameObject parent in prefabParentsOfDoorsNeedRemove)
        {
            Modify(parent, RemoveFunc);
        }

        HashSet<GameObject> prefabParentsOfDoors = new HashSet<GameObject>();
        allDoors.ForEach(doorGameObject =>
        {
            GameObject outermostPrefabInstanceRoot = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(doorGameObject);
            prefabParentsOfDoors.Add(outermostPrefabInstanceRoot);
        });

        foreach (GameObject parent in prefabParentsOfDoors)
        {
            AddShaderToPrefab(parent);
        }
    }

    private void AddShaderToPrefab(GameObject child)
    {
        Modify(child, AddShaderToAllDoorsFunc);
    }

    private GameObject AddShaderToAllDoorsFunc(GameObject prefab)
    {
        var children = prefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

        //Debug.Log($"Total child count before:{children.Count()}");
        int doorsFound = 0;
        foreach (Transform trans in children)
        {
            if (trans.name == c_doorLeft || (trans.name == c_doorRight))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Found door, adding");
                GameObject shader = GetDoorShaderPrefab();

                // clone prefab and attach to parent
                Instantiate(shader, trans); 
                doorsFound++;
            }
        }

        children = prefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        //Debug.Log($"Total child count after:{children.Count()}, doors found:{doorsFound}");

        return prefab;
    }

    private GameObject GetDoorShaderPrefab()
    {
        string[] shieldPrefab = AssetDatabase.FindAssets(c_doorShieldFxLocked);
        //Debug.Assert(shieldPrefab.Length == 1, "Expected exactly 1 shield like this...");
        string shieldGuid = shieldPrefab[0];
        string prefabPath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(shieldGuid);
        GameObject prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(prefabPath);
        //Debug.Assert(prefab != null, "Expected prefab to load");
        return prefab;
    }

    private GameObject RemoveFunc(GameObject prefab)
    {
        var children = prefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

        //Debug.Log($"child count:{children.Count()}");
        foreach (Transform trans in children)
        {
            if (trans.name.StartsWith(c_doorShieldFxLocked))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Found door shader");
                DestroyImmediate(trans.gameObject);
            }
        }

        children = prefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        //Debug.Log($"child count:{children.Count()}");

        return prefab;
    }

    private void Modify(GameObject parentPrefab, Func<GameObject,GameObject> modifyActionOnPrefab)
    {
        // Get the Prefab Asset root GameObject and its asset path.
        string assetPath = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot(parentPrefab);

        // Load the contents of the Prefab Asset.
        GameObject prefab = PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents(assetPath);

        //PrefabUtility.UnpackPrefabInstance(mostPrefabInstanceRoot, PrefabUnpackMode.Completely, UnityEditor.InteractionMode.AutomatedAction);

        prefab = modifyActionOnPrefab(prefab);

        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(prefab, assetPath);
        PrefabUtility.UnloadPrefabContents(prefab);
    }
}
```

I want to do it in the method DeleteAllShaders.
Now the function RemoveFunc will remove only the shaders childs that are under specific prefabs and parents.

I want to give a choice to destroy all the shaders in the world including shaders that are under prefabs.
Maybe to use the RemoveFunc but in this case I don't want to add a new shaders only to destroy.

I'm using AllParents flag to decide if to get all the doors left and right in the world or if to get the doors left and right under specific parents. When AllParents is true then I want to be able to delete all the shaders in the world those under any of the doors and those that not under any doors. All the shaders.

Comment: This questions title has "supervillain" written all over it, and made me guffaw out loud at work.

Comment: Do you need nested children or only direct children of the `prefab`?

Comment: Your usage of the name `prefab` is a bit strange! A Prefab is a template object that lives only on the Assets. When talking about objects in the scene do not call them `prefab` rather use e.g. `obj`. It is therefore unclear for me: Do you really want to delete children in actual Prefabs or are you talking about objects in the scene?

Comment: Found how to do it using a flag and it's working fine now.